# REXML::Document.new can we give encode parameters on this line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rexml

doc = REXML::Document.new file
My code is failing at this point whenever my xml file contains some special characters other than UTF-8 .

```
REXML::ParseException (#<REXML::ParseException: #<ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call something like this

```
REXML::Document.new(file.force_encoding("FILE_ENCODING").encode("UTF-8"))
```

FILE_ENCODING is the encoding of your file variable.

Comment: I tried but get undefined method error for file ... here is what i have done  ......  file =File.open(file_name)   ....... 
doc = REXML::Document.new(file.force_encoding("UTF-8"))   ... my file is UTF-8 by default as its an XML file  .....

Comment: The file should be text. How can you have non-utf8 characters in utf-8 file?

Comment: I loading the .XML files.. I think there is a copy paste step from browser while generating the XML ..... so it has some non UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Right now am using this step : REXML::Document.new(File.open(file_name,"r:iso-8859-1:utf-8")) solves my problem ...but am not sure how it works ! Do you have any idea on this ?

Comment: Well, this reencodes your file when opening, so you don't have problems with this. My function above does the same, but on the file contents.

Comment: But i am not sure why .... I tried your function gives me an error ... did I give it correctly in the first comment ?? and what is :iso-8859-1 does it take the entire XML characters even if they are special characters ?? how does it wrk ?

Comment: data = File.read("/path/to/file"); data.force_encoding("FILE_ENCODING").encode("UTF-8"); -- I was thinking of this.

Comment: ok will try that too ... Thanks so much for taking out time to reply my queries :)