# CSV read v/s Temp table read from database, optimization of the loop and active record usage . Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

CSV parsing of the file was very slow so I was trying to load the file directly in to some temp table in database directly and then doing the computation as below :

Earlier it was like this, took 13 mins to add the entries using below method :

```
CSV.foreach(fileName) do |line|
     completePath = line[0]                                                
    num_of_bps = line[1]

    completePath = cluster_path+ '/' + completePath
    inode = FileOrFolder.find_by_fullpath(completePath, :select=>"id") 

    metric_instance = MetricInstance.find(:first, :conditions=>["file_or_folder_id = ? AND dataset_id = ?", inode.id, dataset_id])
    add_entry(metric_instance.id, num_of_bps, num_of_bp_tests) 
end



def self.add_entry(metaid, num_of_bps, num_of_bp_tests)
    entry = Bp.new
    entry.metric_instance_id = metaid
    entry.num_of_bps = num_of_bps
    entry.num_of_bp_tests = num_of_bp_tests
    entry.save
    return entry
end
```

now I changed the method to this, now takes 52 mins :(

```
@bps = TempTable.all

      @bps.each do |bp|
      completePath = bp.first_column
      num_of_bps = bp.second_column
      num_of_bps3 = bp.third_column


completePath = cluster_path+ '/' + completePath
      inode = FileOrFolder.find_by_fullpath(completePath, :select=>"id")     
      num_of_bp_tests = 0
       if(inode.nil?)
       else
          if(num_of_bps !='0')
            num_of_bp_tests = 1
          end

          metric_instance = MetricInstance.find(:first, :conditions=>["file_or_folder_id = ? AND dataset_id = ?", inode.id, dataset_id])
          add_entry(metric_instance.id, num_of_bps, num_of_bp_tests)
         end
end
```

Please help me optimize this code or let me know if you think CSV.each is faster than database read !

Comment: What database are you on?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment in the other thread.  I am saying, now that the data is in the database, *forget about ruby*.  Just build the new records with a plain old `INSERT`+`SELECT` statement.  Can you post the DDL for the temp and target tables?

Comment: I am sorry I dint get you ..... I am trying to read the entries from a file CSV.foreach and then check for those entries in some other tables and then add the entry finally to the database table using this method .....add_entry(metric_instance.id, num_of_bps, num_of_bp_tests)

Answer (score 0):

When you load csv into database you do:

- load N csv lines
- insert N records int DB
- select and instantiate N active record models
- iterate over its

When you work with raw csv you only

- load N csv lines
- iterate over its

Of course it's faster.

Comment: Ok . is there any way i can optimize my CSV read .... CSV.foreach(fileName) do |line| ....its slow and i have several records to load by this way and it takes 9 hrs to load evrything in to database ..... so just wanted to try the database way , just with a hope that it would be faster ...but then it was even slower

Comment: btw, if you'll use `TempTable.find_each` instead of `@bps.each` - the second script will become faster.

Comment: thanks .... but do you think CSV way is much faster than this way ??? is there any way i cann improve CSV read ???