# Using Closure_tree gem instead of Awesome nested set

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Hi I followed the [link](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree#available-options) to set up closure_tag gem.

When i tried to use closure_tree syntax in the following way (newStructure.find_or_create_by_path(parent) instead of newStructure.move_to_child_of(parent)) ... got the following error :

*"Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ancestor, descendant, generations"*

is this the correct way of using newStructure.find_or_create_by_path(parent) ?

```
def self.import(path)

    newStructure = FileOrFolder.find(:first, :conditions=>["fullpath = ?", path])
    if newStructure
      return newStructure
    end

    newStructure = FileOrFolder.new
    newStructure.fullpath = path
    pathbits = path.split('/')
    newStructure.name = pathbits.last
    newStructure.save




    parentpath = path.sub(/#{Regexp.escape(pathbits.last)}$/, '')
        if parentpath.length > 1
          parentpath.sub!(/\/$/,'')
          parent = FileOrFolder.find(:first, :conditions=>["fullpath = ?", parentpath])
          unless parent
            parent = FileOrFolder.import(parentpath)
          end
          #newStructure.move_to_child_of(parent);
          **newStructure.find_or_create_by_path(parent);**
        end
        newStructure.save
        return newStructure

      end






database table looks like : 

mysql> select * from testdb7.file_or_folders limit 10;
+------+-----------+------+------+----------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | parent_id | lft  | rgt  | fullpath | name                   | created_at          | updated_at          |
+------+-----------+------+------+----------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 6901 |      NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL     |                        | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
| 6902 |      6901 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | devel                  | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
| 6903 |      6902 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | Bcontrol               | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
| 6904 |      6903 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | perfect                | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
| 6905 |      6904 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | matlab                 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
| 6906 |      6905 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | test                   | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
| 6907 |      6906 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | smoke                  | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
| 6908 |      6907 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | Control_System_Toolbox | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
| 6909 |      6908 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | tsmoke_are.m           | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
| 6910 |      6908 | NULL | NULL | NULL     | tsmoke_bode.m          | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 | 2013-06-25 18:49:04 |
+------+-----------+------+------+----------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+



FileOrFolder Load (14560.8ms)  SELECT `file_or_folders`.* FROM `file_or_folders` INNER JOIN `file_or_folder_hierarchies` ON `file_or_folders`.`id` = `file_or_folder_hierarchies`.`descendant_id` INNER JOIN (
 SELECT ancestor_id
 FROM `file_or_folder_hierarchies`
 GROUP BY 1
 HAVING MAX(`file_or_folder_hierarchies`.generations) = 0
 ) AS leaves ON (`file_or_folders`.id = leaves.ancestor_id) WHERE `file_or_folder_hierarchies`.`ancestor_id` = 147 ORDER BY `file_or_folder_hierarchies`.generations asc
  EXPLAIN (13343.7ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT `file_or_folders`.* FROM `file_or_folders` INNER JOIN `file_or_folder_hierarchies` ON `file_or_folders`.`id` = `file_or_folder_hierarchies`.`descendant_id` INNER JOIN (
 SELECT ancestor_id
 FROM `file_or_folder_hierarchies`
 GROUP BY 1
 HAVING MAX(`file_or_folder_hierarchies`.generations) = 0
 ) AS leaves ON (`file_or_folders`.id = leaves.ancestor_id) WHERE `file_or_folder_hierarchies`.`ancestor_id` = 147 ORDER BY `file_or_folder_hierarchies`.generations asc
EXPLAIN for: SELECT `file_or_folders`.* FROM `file_or_folders` INNER JOIN `file_or_folder_hierarchies` ON `file_or_folders`.`id` = `file_or_folder_hierarchies`.`descendant_id` INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ancestor_id
            FROM `file_or_folder_hierarchies`
            GROUP BY 1
            HAVING MAX(`file_or_folder_hierarchies`.generations) = 0
          ) AS leaves ON (`file_or_folders`.id = leaves.ancestor_id) WHERE `file_or_folder_hierarchies`.`ancestor_id` = 147 ORDER BY `file_or_folder_hierarchies`.generations asc
+----+-------------+----------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | type   | possible_keys                                                                      | key                              | key_len | ref                | rows    | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | file_or_folder_hierarchies | ref    | index_file_or_folders_on_ans_des,index_file_or_folder_hierarchies_on_descendant_id | index_file_or_folders_on_ans_des | 4       | const              |      15 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>                 | ALL    | NULL                                                                               | NULL                             | NULL    | NULL               |  104704 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | file_or_folders            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                            | PRIMARY                          | 4       | leaves.ancestor_id |       1 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | file_or_folder_hierarchies | index  | NULL                                                                               | index_file_or_folders_on_ans_des | 8       | NULL               | 1340096 |                                 |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm suffering the same error, I think 4.2.2 has a bug

Comment: and even if I try to use ..... grandparent = newStructure.new(:name => "Grandparent") ... i get NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for #FileOrFolder:0x)

Comment: @GabrielMazetto did you face this error as well .... i get this error when i try to use it with 4.2.1 version as well

Comment: Stay tuned with https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree/issues/66

Comment: yeah thanks... I had a look at this and I moved to 4.2.1 version and the above error is solved ...but what is the alternative to .move_to_child_of in closure_tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of closure_tree. 4.2.3 is on it's way with the fix for attr_accessible. I'm just waiting for Travis to finish testing it.

It looks like your whole `import`  method could be replaced with this line:

```
# Assumes that path is a string that looks like this: "/usr/local/bin/ruby"
def import(path)
  FileOrFolder.find_or_create_by_path(path.split("/"))
end
```

This assumes you have this FileOrFolder setup:

```
class FileOrFolder < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
  before_create :set_fullpath
  def set_fullpath
    if root?
      self.fullpath = "/#{name}"
    else
      self.fullpath = "/#{parent.ancestry_path.join("/")}/#{name}"
    end
  end
end
```

Please take a look at the [spec](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree/tree/master/spec) directory. You'll find *tons* of other examples.

Comment: @mrm...  Thanks for the reply. ...I made the changes you mentioned..and the entries are being added as expected, just that fullpath is not being populated correctly ..... the column is empty in the table...could you please help.

Comment: edited my post to include the database entries ...after these changes !

Comment: Updated the answer, try that.

Comment: .....I could implement closure_tree ...finally ...but its taking a lot of time than awesome_nested_set for retrieval ..... awesome_nested_set was more fast than this gem :( ....i am not sure if am missing something ..functionality is working as expected ..but performance wise its very very slow...

Comment: i have edited my post to include the explain description of my console and the load time taken ....